# NET-SNMP agent trap v3 configuration

Tags: c, net-snmp

Im trying to implement agent trap v3 sender using net-snmp.

currently my status is im able to start snmpd and daemon is sending coldstart trap to host defined in snmpd.conf

my snmpd.conf:

```
createUser myuser SHA "12345678" AES

rouser myuser auth


trapsess -v 3 -u myuser -n contextname -l authPriv -a SHA -A 12345678 -x AES -        X 12345678 host_ip:162


group groupv3            usm      myuser

##          incl/excl subtree                         mask
view all    included  .1                               80

access groupv3         ""        any       auth      exact    all         all             all
```

var/net-snmp/snmpd.conf contain the hash user, if im using snmptrap command in linux i can see the trap recived by host with wireshark sniffer.

But im unable to send traps from code (im restricted to C, embedded system).
im using send_v2trap() api, and when im defined vars list nothing is sent out. im not sure what i need to define, do i need to open session or snmpd.conf file is enough? what i need to define to send trap via code?

i tried to use some examples provided with no luck

this is one of them:

```
int
write_exampletrap2(int action,
                   u_char * var_val,
                   u_char var_val_type,
                   size_t var_val_len,
                   u_char * statP, oid * name, size_t name_len)
{
    long            intval;

    /*
     * these variales will be used when we send the trap 
     */
    oid             objid_snmptrap[] = { 1, 3, 6, 1, 6, 3, 1, 1, 4, 1, 0 };     /* snmpTrapOID.0 */
    oid             demo_trap[] = { 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2021, 13, 990 };  /*demo-trap */
    oid             example_string_oid[] =
        { 1, 3, 6, 1, 4, 1, 2021, 254, 1, 0 };
    static netsnmp_variable_list var_trap;
    static netsnmp_variable_list var_obj;

    DEBUGMSGTL(("example", "write_exampletrap2 entered: action=%d\n",
                action));
    switch (action) {
    case RESERVE1:
        /*
         *  The only acceptable value is the integer 1
         */
        if (var_val_type != ASN_INTEGER) {
            DEBUGMSGTL(("example", "%x not integer type", var_val_type));
            return SNMP_ERR_WRONGTYPE;
        }
        if (var_val_len > sizeof(long)) {
            DEBUGMSGTL(("example", "wrong length %" NETSNMP_PRIz "u",
                        var_val_len));
            return SNMP_ERR_WRONGLENGTH;
        }

        intval = *((long *) var_val);
        if (intval != 1) {
            DEBUGMSGTL(("example", "wrong value %lx", intval));
            return SNMP_ERR_WRONGVALUE;
        }
        break;

    case RESERVE2:
        /*
         * No resources are required.... 
         */
        break;

    case FREE:
        /*
         * ... so no resources need be freed 
         */
        break;

    case ACTION:
        /*
         *  Having triggered the sending of a trap,
         *   it would be impossible to revoke this,
         *   so we can't actually invoke the action here.
         */
        break;

    case UNDO:
        /*
         * We haven't done anything yet,
         * so there's nothing to undo 
         */
        break;

    case COMMIT:
        /*
         *  Everything else worked, so it's now safe
         *   to trigger the trap.
         *  Note that this is *only* acceptable since
         *   the trap sending routines are "failsafe".
         *  (In fact, they can fail, but they return no
         *   indication of this, which is the next best thing!)
         */

        /*
         * trap definition objects 
         */

        var_trap.next_variable = &var_obj;      /* next variable */
        var_trap.name = objid_snmptrap; /* snmpTrapOID.0 */
        var_trap.name_length = sizeof(objid_snmptrap) / sizeof(oid);    /* number of sub-ids */
        var_trap.type = ASN_OBJECT_ID;
        var_trap.val.objid = demo_trap; /* demo-trap objid */
        var_trap.val_len = sizeof(demo_trap);   /* length in bytes (not number of subids!) */


        /*
         * additional objects 
         */


        var_obj.next_variable = NULL;   /* No more variables after this one */
        var_obj.name = example_string_oid;
        var_obj.name_length = sizeof(example_string_oid) / sizeof(oid); /* number of sub-ids */
        var_obj.type = ASN_OCTET_STR;   /* type of variable */
        var_obj.val.string = (unsigned char *) example_str;       /* value */
        var_obj.val_len = strlen(example_str);
        DEBUGMSGTL(("example", "write_exampletrap2 sending the v2 trap\n"));
        send_v2trap(&var_trap);
        DEBUGMSGTL(("example", "write_exampletrap2 v2 trap sent\n"));

        break;

    }
    return SNMP_ERR_NOERROR;
}
```

any help or example will be very appreciated

Thanks in advance